# watershed algorithm raises ERROR: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC3 && dst.type() == CV_32SC1 in function 'watershed'

Tags: python, opencv

I am following the [opencv watershed algorithm tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html), I am just using a different start image.

Everything goes fine until I get to the markers.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

# NOISE REMOVAL WITH ELABORATE THRESHOLD

img_blur = cv2.medianBlur(img, ksize=15)
THRESH_SUM = cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU    
ret, thresh_summed_thresh = cv2.threshold(img_blur, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_summed_thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5 )
dist_transform_normalized = cv2.normalize(dist_transform, None, 0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# SURE FOREGROUND, BACKGROUND, UNKNOWN REGION

ret, sure_foreground = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.7*dist_transform.max(), 255,  0)
sure_foreground_uint8 = np.uint8(sure_foreground)

sure_background = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=3)
sure_background_uint8 = np.uint8(sure_background)

unknown_region = cv2.subtract(sure_background, sure_foreground_uint8)

# MARKERS
 
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_foreground_uint8)
markers = markers + 1
markers[unknown_region==255] = 0
 
# only to show the image on VS code
markers_normalized = cv2.normalize(markers, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
markers_normalized_uint8 = np.uint8(markers_normalized)
```

But when I try to run the watershed algorithm,

```
watershed_img = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
```

this error is raised

> watershed_img = cv2.watershed(img, markers) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0)
> /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/segmentation.cpp:161: error:
> (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC3 && dst.type() ==
> CV_32SC1 in function 'watershed'

What could be the problem?

Some info

```
print(img.shape, markers.shape)
(405, 304) (405, 304)
 
print(type(img), type(markers))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Your input image `img` is grayscale (you explicitly convert it after loading). Yet, the docs of [`watershed`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d47/group__imgproc__segmentation.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1) state this about the first argument: "Input 8-bit 3-channel image.".

Comment: Right.  The input `CV_8UC3` means pixels have three components of 8-bit unsigned values.  That is, RGB.  The output `CV_32SC1` means those pixels have one component that is a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: In this case, `img.shape` should be `(405, 304, 3)` (which it is not) and `img.dtype` should be `dtype('uint8')` (which I think it is). `markers.shape` is correct, and since it came from `connectedComponents`, `markers.dtype` should already be `dtype('int32')`, so that's all good, | Hint: When dealing with numpy arrays, it's also important to inspect the `dtype` property -- while they are both `ndarray`s, each represents an array of a elements of a different data type.

Comment: Thank you everybody. There are some precious indications in these comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @Tim Roberts and @Dan Mašek, 
the first input of the watershed function must be "Input 8-bit 3-channel image" (`CV_8UC3`), while I had a grayscale (`CV_32SC1`).

So I substituted the grayscale image with the original one

```
watershed_img = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
```

with

```
img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
watershed_img = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
```

Also, to display the `watershed_img` and appreciate the variation of its colours I had to normalize it and turn it into uint8

```
watershed_img_normalized = cv2.normalize(watershed_img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
watershed_img_normalized_uint8 = np.uint8(watershed_img_normalized)
```